# Downloading files from google storage using Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download the .csv of my app reviews on the play store and import it into google sheets using Google Scripts.

Is there a way to access google storage with Google scripts?

I want to retrieve the files from my bucket
Eg) gs://pubsite_prod_rev_0123456789/reviews/reviews_com.example.app_2013*

Answer (score 2):

If the object is publicly readable, you can import it like any other URL:

```
IMPORTDATA("http://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name")
```

The wildcard character, `*`, won't work, though. IMPORTDATA only accepts a single URL at a time.

Comment: What can I do if the object needs authentication?

Comment: Hrm, good question. I think it'd be somewhat tricky, but you'd want to set up a service account that has access to the data, then get a refresh token for it and use that token and use UrlFetchApp.fetch stuff to retrieve the CSV file and load it. Would probably be rather more painful than using IMPORTDATA.